# Set SelectAction on all tree nodes for ASP.NET TreeView control

Tags: c#, web-controls

I have a TreeView web control on an ASP page. I am programmatically populating all the tree nodes. I want to disable the link on ALL tree nodes. I can do it one at a time, like this (using a string array for simplicity's sake):

```
for each (string strValue in strValues)
{
TreeNode objNode = new TreeNode(strValue);
objNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
objTreeView.Nodes.Add(objNode);
}
```

Assume for the sake of argument that I have multiple level of nodes, so there is not a simple way to iterate through all nodes once I am done populating. Is there a property I can set on the TreeView to set SelectAction for all nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeView does not support any property to do this. However you can do it by using recursive methods

Comment: Thanks. I am just setting the SelectAction as I create each node, it doesn't make sense to loop through them all again. I had hoped there was a property at the TreeView level to disable for all nodes, much like "objTreeView.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.None".

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processNode(trvTest.Nodes);
    }

    private void processNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                processNode(node.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you took what I wrote and made it recursive. But what I was looking for was a property to set ALL nodes to none by default. I didn't want to have to loop through all nodes. But thanks.